# Is something wrong with my hard disk?

Tags: windows-10, ubuntu, hard-drive

A few days ago, when I was using Windows 10, and I kept getting the "[black screen with cursor](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-desktop/windows-10-black-screen-with-cursor/f8502479-2960-45e4-abf6-7e77cc278467?auth=1)`" issue. After trying my luck with several fixes suggested online (using ctrl or spacebar to activate the password field, and logging in, using Ctrl + P to start the project dialog and try and change the display device, disabling and uninstalling the display adapter etc.), I reinstalled windows. Then the following series of events happened:

1. The computer was extremely slow.
2. I saw that the Intel HD Graphics driver that I uninstalled was no replaced with a "Microsoft Basic Graphics Driver", and I got a notification that the system's performance or graphics may be affected until a suitable driver is found.
3. I reinstalled the Intel HD Graphics Driver.
4. The laptop was still *very* slow --it felt like I was using a laptop from 2005.
5. I couldn't install programs (tried Google Chrome), and got an Input / Output error Oxc000009c.
6. After trying everything I could, I decided I'll just try installing Ubuntu.
7. Ubuntu, like Windows 10, booted extremely slowly again, but once it's up and running, it was normal
8. I sometimes get an I/O error, and I sometimes have trouble installing software packages on Ubuntu using the software center (it works fine while using the Terminal).

Comment: Back up your data and run a hard drive test across it. Ideally from a boot disk, but there are tools you can run from within either OS too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All recent HDD and SDD can produce [SMART](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S.M.A.R.T.) diagnostics.

On Ubuntu, install the `smartmontools` package and see what the SMART data are telling you about your disk (see the `smartctl` command). You can possibly also run this from an Ubuntu live CD or any Linux distro specialized in repairs, for instance [SystemRescueCD](http://www.system-rescue-cd.org/). You can find a list of other Live CD with SmartMonTools [here](https://www.smartmontools.org/wiki/LiveCDs) and of course on the same site some information on how to use the tools.

Me, I don't take any chances, unless the SMART data re squeaky clean I replace the disk, and leave the old one (after careful erasure) where my enemies think they can steal it :).

Comment: I ran Dell's pre-boot diagnostics, and it showed that the hard disk was dead. Thanks.